# Iron golem farm not working 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently built an Iron golem farm on a multiplayer server (1.15.2).
Here is a screenshot from above:

[image: screenshot]

I have tried resetting their profession and changing their beds twice now and waiting for a full day night cycle but that was without success. I understand that multiplayer servers have a global mob cap but even when I am the only one online on the server the Iron Golems don't spawn.

I have 3 villagers in each pod, by the way.

I have a villager breeder nearby, and a place where I keep a ton of villagers pretty close, does that affect the spawning of the iron golems? I do see some Iron Golems spawning near the breeder from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged back into the server and it started working again, no idea what has changed!

Answer (score 0):

The ones in the end I can see is far too far away to get scared ... The max distance for a Zombie is 8 blocks ... And for that setup (docM77s) to work, the distance between the villagers and the zombie should be four blocks for the whole line of sight thing to work both day and night.

Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. But I don't understand, the distance between the zombie and the villager pods on the end are 4 blocks since there is a zombie in between the 2 pods.